# Topology of statistical manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, probability-distributions

I am currently working with statistical manifolds. Roughly, a statistical manifold is a set of distribution parametrized by a set of parameters. However i have trouble finding more precise definition. In order to be a manifold, a set is supposed to be locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. The word homeomorphic assume that the set of distributions is initially equipped with a topology.

My question is the following: what is the initial topology on the set of distributions when one speaks of statistical manifolds?

Thanks

Comment: From the Wikipedia article, a statistical manifold is a Riemannian manifold whose points are probability distributions on some fixed set with some fixed $\sigma$-algebra. This space comes with a Riemannian metric, which is usually the Fisher information metric. This Riemannian metric induces the topology of the manifold.

Comment: Ok, here you assume that a statistical manifold is a Riemannian manifold. Then the question is, which topology do you put on the set of distributions before saying it is a (Riemannian) manifold.

Comment: In practice you don't start with the topology, you get the topology from the metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this answer isn't too late, but if you want to be rigorous about it, take the weak topology on your measure space (this is assuming your measure is Borel (or a completion of Borel) w.r.t. some topology that was already on the space; if that's not the case, then I don't believe one can make sense of the definitions.)

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnms/1215467061

In practice, of course, families we care about are parametrized in an obvious way by subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and get their topology that way.